# How to tell if MVC AsyncController Thread is execution in ASP.NET Pool or I/O Completion Port

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.  I'm using AsyncController and creating new threads.  Is there a way to validate that I'm using I/O completion ports instead of ASP.NET Thread Pool?

Is there a property in Thread.CurrentThread or someplace else that I can check to identify where the thread is running?

Here a example of the code that I'm executing

```
public class HomeController : AsyncController
{
    public void CarsComplexAsync(string make)
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment(2);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Enter CarsComplexAsync: " + DateTime.Now);

        Action getCarsAsync = () =>
        {
            List<Car> cars = CarService.GetCars(make);
            AsyncManager.Parameters["cars"] = cars;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();    
        };


        Action getTrucksAsync = () =>
        {
            List<Car> trucks = CarService.GetTrucks(make);
            AsyncManager.Parameters["trucks"] = trucks;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        };


        getCarsAsync.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        getTrucksAsync.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
```

---

```
public ActionResult CarsComplexCompleted(List<Car> cars, List<Car> trucks)
{
cars.AddRange(trucks);
return View(cars);
}
```

---

```
public static class CarService
{
    private static List<Car> _cars = new List<Car>
                {
                    new Car{ Make = "Ford", Model = "F-150", Color = "White", Year = 2010},
                    new Car{ Make = "Chevy", Model = "Camero", Color = "Black", Year = 1984},
                    new Car{ Make = "Peugeot", Model = "406 Coupe", Color = "White", Year = 2010},
                    new Car{ Make = "Dodge", Model = "Charger", Color = "Red", Year = 1974}
                };

    public static List<Car> GetCars(string model)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        List<Car> cars = _cars;
        return cars;
    }

    public  static List<Car> GetTrucks(string make)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        List<Car> cars = _cars;
        return cars;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to validate that I'm using I/O completion ports instead of ASP.NET Thread Pool?

Not without seeing your code as it will depend on the APIs you are using.

For example [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) uses I/O Completion Ports. On the other hand if you have some CPU intensive task that you are running on a separate thread that you've created manually then you are not using I/O Completion Ports.

> Is there a property in Thread.CurrentThread or someplace else that I can check to identify where the thread is running?

A Completion Port means that there is no thread because if there was a thread its as if you were running on a thread. Basically the way I/O Completion Ports work is that you start some I/O operation and a CP is registered with it, then you free all threads and return. During the execution of the operation there are no threads in your application associated to it. Once the operation completes the port is signaled and a thread is cretad/drawn from the pool to end the request.

Comment: I probably should have added a car that is made in france.

Comment: @BarDev, now that you have shown your example, it doesn't involve any I/O Completion Ports. The operations are executed on a thread from the pool which is being monopolized during their execution. Here's [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx) of an AsyncController which calls a remote web service and uses I/O Completion Ports. IOCP are often used when dealing with remote systems such as web service calls, database calls and even file I/O with Stream.BeginRead, ...

Comment: @Darin, Thanks for the answer. I didn't want to change any code in the service to make my application use I/O Completion Ports. I was wishing I could just change the action and everything would work with I/O Completion Ports. Time to change the POC and try it again.

Comment: @Darin, I think I figured out my problem and was wondering if you could confirm it. First I Added the following code to my service `Debug.WriteLine("IsThreadPoolThread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);`. When I run this in the current implementation I get true. But if I change `Action getCarsAsync = () =>` to `Thread callGetCars = new Thread(() =>` and call Start on the thread, I get false.

Comment: @BarDev, in the first case you are using a thread from the thread pool because you are calling the `BeginInvoke` method on the Action delegate you created. In the second case you are getting false because you are manually spawning a new thread (`new Thread()`). But in both cases you are **not using** an IOCP => you are using a thread which in the first case is drawn from a pool and in the second case is manually created.